# finding directory entries that contain at least one subdirectory from a list

Tags: grep, file-search

I have a file which contains directories and subdirectories and I need to search for lines which are subdirectories. I used the `grep` command to perform the action but it does not work. Can you please let me know how to perform this action?

For example a file called a.txt has the below data:

```
.
./vou
./vou/bin
./vou/ctl
./vou2
./vou2/test
```

The end result should be:

```
./vou/bin
./vou/ctl
./vou2/test
```

Comment: Did you try `grep '/.*/' a.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `egrep` like

```
egrep "/[^/]+/" <file>
```

which will find a `/` then anything that is not a slash at least one time, then another `/`

Of course, this looks like the output of a `find` command, so you could instead just use the `-mindepth 2` option like

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d
```